# How to create Online IDW(Inverse Distance Weighted) Interpolation?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, interpolation

I have some point data  which store as JSON.As follow:
                `[["Lat":"12.12","Long":"23.23","ZValue":"123"],...]`.

I tried to interpolate them as contour line and displayed them on my website ? I do know how to interpolate data in ArcInfo,so I tried to publish a geoprocessing  task and using ArcGIS JavaScript API to generate them but it failed to published to ArcServer.[image]

However,I search for a long time if there exits some other solution but found nothing about how to implement this.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: I also doubt geoprocessing task to handle my json data.

Answer (score 1):

To publish your IDW raster, you have two options

---

Option1:
This will require you to export your model builder into python code and work from there. Your steps will be

1. Add the resulting IDW raster as a layer to a map document and save it
2. Create a Service Definition Draft using the map document using arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft() method
3. Next stage your SDDraft into a service definition file using arcpy.StageService_server() method
4. Finally you need to upload the .sd file to a server. You will use arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server() method. For this you must create a server connection file (.ags)

The help link is: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Publishing_toolset/00540000001q000000/

---

**Option2**
You can use the model builder to create output IDW rasters then use ArcGIS Desktop to publish it. This is not fully automated but a solution if you are not comfortable writing python scripts.
The help for this is: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/How_to_publish_a_service/0154000004n3000000/

Answer (score -1):

you must create the interpolation surface then from catalog publish the .mxd contain the interpolation surface

Comment: Could you edit your post to expound upon this a bit and/or cite this information?